# Select nao retorna os valores corretamente por mês

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho uma tabela com um campo onde fica o valor(saldo_atual) e nesta tabela tem uma coluna (periodo), onde tem a data que desejo verificar, entretanto, quando executo a Query abaixo só retorna o mês 1 os outros períodos retorna Null, o que pode ser ?

Query que eu estou usando abaixo.

```
SELECT classificacao, descricao, saldo_anterior,
        (SELECT saldo_atual WHERE MONTH(periodo) = 1)  AS Janeiro,
        (SELECT saldo_atual WHERE MONTH(periodo) = 2) AS Feveiro,
        (SELECT saldo_atual WHERE MONTH(periodo) = 3) AS Marco,
        (SELECT saldo_atual WHERE MONTH(periodo) = 4) AS Abril,
        (SELECT saldo_atual WHERE MONTH(periodo) = 5) AS Maio,
        (SELECT saldo_atual WHERE MONTH(periodo) = 6) AS Junho,
        (SELECT saldo_atual WHERE MONTH(periodo) = 7) AS Julho,
        (SELECT saldo_atual WHERE MONTH(periodo) = 8) AS Agosto,
        (SELECT saldo_atual WHERE MONTH(periodo) = 9) AS Setembro,
        (SELECT saldo_atual WHERE MONTH(periodo) = 10) AS Outubro,
        (SELECT saldo_atual WHERE MONTH(periodo) = 11) AS Novembro,
        (SELECT saldo_atual WHERE MONTH(periodo) = 12) AS Dezembro
    FROM tbl_balancete
    GROUP BY classificacao, descricao
    ;
```

Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estrutura do banco e simulação do erro

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wKGRhVU5bZntL1KCiA34fy/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar o CASE WHEn THEN ELSE END

```
SELECT classificacao, descricao, saldo_anterior,
         CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo)=1 THEN saldo_atual  ELSE  0  END AS Janeiro,
         CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo)=2 THEN saldo_atual  ELSE  0  END AS Fevereiro,
         CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo)=3 THEN saldo_atual  ELSE  0  END AS Marco,
         CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo)=4 THEN saldo_atual  ELSE  0  END AS AS Abril,
         CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo)=4 THEN saldo_atual  ELSE  0  END AS Maio,
         CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo)=6 THEN saldo_atual  ELSE  0  END AS Junho,
         CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo)=7 THEN saldo_atual  ELSE  0  END AS Julho,
         CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo)=8 THEN saldo_atual  ELSE  0  END AS Agosto,
         CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo)=9 THEN saldo_atual  ELSE  0  END AS Setembro,
         CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo)=10 THEN saldo_atual  ELSE  0  END AS Outubro,
         CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo)=11 THEN saldo_atual  ELSE  0  END AS Novembro,
         CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo)=12 THEN saldo_atual  ELSE  0  END AS Dezembro
    FROM tbl_balancete
    GROUP BY classificacao, descricao
    ;
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Com base na estrutura posteriormente fornecida extrapolei uma possível solução com os somatórios por ano.

1º *subquery* obtêm lista  única de classificações por ano, descrição e saldo actual

2º *subquery* faz o *pivot* por ano classificação e meses

O ultimo query faz o *left join*  dos dois anteriores agregando por ano, classificacao, descricao e  saldo_anterior e soma os  valores obtidos para cada mês

```
SELECT plano.ano,
       plano.classificacao,
       plano.descricao,
       plano.saldo_anterior,
       SUM(Janeiro) AS Janeiro,
       SUM(Fevereiro) AS Fevereiro,
       SUM(Marco) AS Marco,
       SUM(Abril) AS Abril,
       SUM(Maio) AS Maio,
       SUM(Junho) AS Junho,
       SUM(Julho) AS Julho,
       SUM(Agosto) AS Agosto,
       SUM(Setembro) AS Setembro,
       SUM(Outubro) AS Outubro,
       SUM(Novembro) AS Novembro,
       SUM(Dezembro) AS Dezembro
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT classificacao,
                   descricao,
                   saldo_anterior,
                   year(periodo) AS Ano
   FROM tbl_balancete) AS plano
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT classificacao,
          year(periodo) AS Ano,
          CASE
              WHEN MONTH(periodo)=1 THEN saldo_atual
              ELSE 0
          END AS Janeiro,
          CASE
              WHEN MONTH(periodo)=2 THEN saldo_atual
              ELSE 0
          END AS Fevereiro,
          CASE
              WHEN MONTH(periodo)=3 THEN saldo_atual
              ELSE 0
          END AS Marco,
          CASE
              WHEN MONTH(periodo)=4 THEN saldo_atual
              ELSE 0
          END AS Abril,
          CASE
              WHEN MONTH(periodo)=4 THEN saldo_atual
              ELSE 0
          END AS Maio,
          CASE
              WHEN MONTH(periodo)=6 THEN saldo_atual
              ELSE 0
          END AS Junho,
          CASE
              WHEN MONTH(periodo)=7 THEN saldo_atual
              ELSE 0
          END AS Julho,
          CASE
              WHEN MONTH(periodo)=8 THEN saldo_atual
              ELSE 0
          END AS Agosto,
          CASE
              WHEN MONTH(periodo)=9 THEN saldo_atual
              ELSE 0
          END AS Setembro,
          CASE
              WHEN MONTH(periodo)=10 THEN saldo_atual
              ELSE 0
          END AS Outubro,
          CASE
              WHEN MONTH(periodo)=11 THEN saldo_atual
              ELSE 0
          END AS Novembro,
          CASE
              WHEN MONTH(periodo)=12 THEN saldo_atual
              ELSE 0
          END AS Dezembro
   FROM tbl_balancete) AS acumulados ON plano.classificacao = acumulados.classificacao
AND plano.ano = acumulados.ano
GROUP BY plano.ano,
         plano.classificacao,
         plano.descricao,
         plano.saldo_anterior
```

Comment: Agora ao invés de retornar Null retorna 0, mas continua sem retornar os meses subsequentes

Comment: Publique a estrutura da tabela

Comment: Pronto coloquei.

Comment: Veja  a atualização

Answer (score 0):

Você não vai ter saldo_atual em um mês que já passou, o saldo é atual. Na sua tabela, quando busca uma conta contabil rodando somente isto:

```
SELECT saldo_atual WHERE MONTH(periodo) = 1
```

O que ele te retorna?

Comment: Retorna a coluna Janeiro que esta na imagem da pergunta no meu caso esse saldo_atual e diferente para cada mês por isso o criterio month(periodo)